# Pdf Writer is not printing all html text after parsing html text with XMLWorkerHelper

Tags: java, html, pdf, itext

I have below **html** text.

```
<p>Use your card when shopping online at Our store and receive 20% off on your very first order.</p> <p>Our store delivers the latest styles at affordable prices for young trendsetters. For those who love putting a sexy spin on their everyday wardrobe, look no further--Our store is the ultimate style destination! Shop the latest pants, dresses and more. Shop now! We've got everything you're looking for.</p> <div> <p>To redeem this offer, click the Redeem button, sign up for our newsletter, and we will email you a discount code, entitling you to 70% off on your first order.</p> </div>
```

And i am parsing it with **XMLWorkerHelper** like below.

```
StringReader strReader = new StringReader("<html><head><style> body {font-family:ArialUnicodeMS; font-size:9pt;} </style></head><body>" + htmlString+"</body></html>");
            try {
                PdfHtmlElementHandler eh = new PdfHtmlElementHandler();
                p = new Paragraph();
                XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(eh, strReader);
                List<Element> htmlList = eh.getHtmlList();
                for(int i=0; i<htmlList.size(); i++) {
                    p.addElement(htmlList.get(i));
                }
            }
           PdfPCell cell_2 = new PdfPCell();
           PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
           cell_2.addElement(p);
           table.addCell(cell_2);
```

Now, See my html text carefully.It has a **`<div>`** tag in the last. After parsing with XMLWorkerHelper, i am adding element in **paragraph** object like this

```
 p.addElement(htmlList.get(i));
```

Now the generated pdf is not displaying the complete text.Its printing text by trimming last `<div>` tag text like below.

Use your card when shopping online at Our store and receive 20% off on your very first order.

Our store delivers the latest styles at affordable prices for young trendsetters. For those who love putting a sexy spin on their everyday wardrobe, look no further--Our store is the ultimate style destination! Shop the latest pants, dresses and more. Shop now! We've got everything you're looking for.

How to resolve this issue.I want full text to be printed.Is this because i am adding into paragraph object?
Because when i used below code.

```
StringReader strReader = new StringReader("<html><head><style> body {font-family:ArialUnicodeMS; font-size:9pt;} </style></head><body>" + htmlString+"</body></html>");
            try {
                PdfHtmlElementHandler eh = new PdfHtmlElementHandler();
                pdfDiv = new PdfDiv();
                XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(eh, strReader);
                List<Element> htmlList = eh.getHtmlList();
                for(int i=0; i<htmlList.size(); i++) {
                    pdfDiv.addElement(htmlList.get(i));
                }
            }
           PdfPCell cell_2 = new PdfPCell();
           PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
           cell_2.addElement(pdfDiv);
           table.addCell(cell_2);
```

Its printing full text.**I just replaced p with pdfDiv**.But i got another issue.

If the text length is large and is not able to be printed on one page,it should be printed on other page.But its not happening in case of pdfDiv.

Summery:-

- **With p its printing on two pages but not the full html text.**
- **With pdfDiv its printing html text fully, but if the text is large
  ,it prints that much text as comes on one pdf page**.

Please help.Its really urgent.I am using **Itext** library for pdf generation.

Comment: Which version? I can't reproduce with the current release, 5.5.7.

Comment: Thanks for reply.I am using 5.3.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved by changing the version of itext from **5.3.2 to 5.5.7**.